# Does a lab consume different potions each at the same speed?

Tags: factorio

Let say I put 10 red, 10 green, 10 blue and 10 violet potions into a single lab.

Does this lab consume different potions each at the same speed?

In this example, will the count of 0 arrive at the same time for the 4 different potions' stacks?

Comment: Going from memory, I believe the answer is "yes"

Answer (score 3):

Everything is at the same pace. You should be able to test this easily, but my reasoning is say you are researching something that takes 100 of each color science packs. The labs will not run unless it has at least 1 of each color in it. Once all colors are present, the consumption begins and research progresses. It wouldn't make sense for them to be consumed at different rates because of this.

If they got consumed at different rates, research would have to work differently. For example, it would cost 200 red, 100 green, 50 blue, and 25 purple science packs for a technology to be researched if it was different rates.

Comment: There are some (late) technologies that do require different amounts of each kind of research. When you're researching these technologies, the science packs are consumed at different rates. For example, in 0.14 Power Armor II costs three times as much Alien science as the other kinds (150, 150, 150, 450). This will consume the Alien science three times as fast as the others.

Comment: @PaulZ looking at the wiki, this appears to be the only technology where 3 packs are used at a time (from a quick skim).  The rate will *technically* be faster for the purple packs (since it processing 3 packs at a time instead of 1), but they should still all reach 0 at the same time, and it should appear that the purple status bar goes down at the same rate as the other packs.  Good observation.

Comment: @PaulZ unless it still consumes 1 purple pack at a time at the same speed as the other packs instead of 3 at a time at the rate.  I've never researched this technology so I can't say for sure.

Comment: The colored bar on the lab screen represents how much of the current (single) science pack is used up. So when researching that tech, the purple bar will drop three times as fast as the others. Combat Robot Damage 3-5 also has uneven costs, as do several of the other multi-level bonus techs. These behave the same way.

Comment: @PaulZ if that is the case, everything should still reach 0 at the same speed.  You'll have 3 times as much purple science that gets used at 3 times the speed thus canceling it out.